# The name 'users' does not exist in the current context

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am attempting to pass a a list of users to a custom component I am developing, however I receive the build error:

The name 'users' does not exist in the current context.

Code:

```
@page "/transactions/list"
@using Accounting.Web.Components.DataTable;

<h3>List</h3>

List

<DataTable Items="users" class="table table-bordered">

</DataTable>

@code {

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }

    public List<User> users { get; set; } = new();

    User user = new()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Username = "Me"
        };

    users.Add(user);   @<< This is where the error occurs
}
```

I can't see where I am going wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instruction need to be encapsulate in method. If you want load data in a component, you can override `OnInitialized` :

```cs
@code {

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }

    public List<User> users { get; set; } = new();

    User user = new()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Username = "Me"
    };

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        users.Add(user);
    }
}
```

But I think you only want data to test the display. In this case you can simplify like :

```cs
@code {

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }

    public List<User> users { get; set; } = new List<User>{
        new User{
            Id = 1,
            Username = "Me"
        },
        new User{
            Id = 2,
            Username = "You"
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Statements can't exist outside a method.

An example

```cs
@code {
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }

    public List<User> users { get; set; } = new();

    User user = new()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Username = "Me"
        };

    // executed when the component is initialized
    // You can use this method to load data
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        users.Add(user);
    }
}
```